# How to read file with \n character in it?

Tags: node.js, file, newline

I read that you can read a file line by line in Node.js like this:

```
var array = require("fs").readFileSync("file").toString().split("\n");
```

But, if the file has a `\n` character in it, it splits that too, so you don't get the file lines the right way.
Is there a way I can read a file with `\n` characters and get the files lines correctly?

For example, how would I split this file?

```
file
print "\n"
exec
```

When I run the above code, it results like this:

```
[ 'file', 'print "\\n"', 'exec' ]
```

Fix?

Comment: If the file has a \n then it is a new line. How can you have \n in a middle of a line ?

Comment: @Sylwit By simply typing `\n`.

Comment: If you type \n it and it doesn't create a new line it mean you have 2 chars \ + n which is not the same as split on "\n".

Comment: Try this `split(String.fromCharCode(10))`

Comment: @bjskistad Please don't hijack your old questions. For "*When module is initialized have all functions become global*", [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (which won't start at -2 votes as well).

Answer (score 2):

From comment above but it's the same as before ...

```
var array = require("fs").readFileSync("file").toString().split(String.fromCharCode(10));
```

Comment: Or you know, just `.split(/\n/g)`

Answer (score 0):

Use an escape.
`var array = require("fs").readFileSync("file").toString().split("\\n");`

Comment: The example you provided does exactly what it is supposed to - it reads the file and splits it into lines. New line is just a newline character. You cannot have newline characters without starting a new line. If you want to preserve the newline characters, you can just add \n at the end of each line.